# How can I filter a specific params key from params passed in a link_to?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, filter, controller

I have an index where users can apply many different kinds of filters through checkboxes.

Each filter has an "X" `link_to` button that dismisses the filter, which basically makes a request to the same index page `permit`ing the current `params` with the exception of the dismissed filter's param key.

For example:

```
<div class="form-group <%= 'hidden' unless params.dig(:q, "subscription_payment_type_eq").present? %>" id="subscription_payment_type_eq" data-toggle-target="objective">
  <%= f.select :subscription_payment_type_eq, payment_types_selector_for_filter,  { include_blank: "Forma de pago..."}, class: "form-control gray my-2 " %>
  <% if params.dig(:q, "subscription_payment_type_eq").present? %>
    <%= link_to admin_users_path(params: params.permit(q: [:extra_params, :address_province_eq, :subscription_status_eq, :created_at_gteq, :created_at_lteq])) do %>
      <span class="dismiss-box glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="form-group <%= 'hidden' unless params.dig(:q, "address_province_eq").present? %>" id="address_province_eq" data-toggle-target="objective">
  <%= f.select :address_province_eq, user_provinces_selector_for_filter, { include_blank: "Provincia..."}, class: "form-control gray my-2 " %>
  <% if params.dig(:q, "address_province_eq").present? %>
    <%= link_to admin_users_path(params: params.permit(q: [:extra_params, :subscription_payment_type_eq, :subscription_status_eq, :created_at_gteq, :created_at_lteq])) do %>
      <span class="dismiss-box glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The approach works, but it's very cumbersome to manually add the excepted param key to each new filter that is added to the index page.

Is there a way to pass params excluding the param key that belongs to the filter being dismissed?

I've tried the following but no params are passed:

```
  <% if params.dig(:q, "subscription_payment_type_eq").present? %>
    <%= link_to admin_users_path(params: params[:q].except(:subscription_payment_type_eq).permit) do %>
      <span class="dismiss-box glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Also tried this but `got undefined method 'exclude' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007f6331b00dd8>`

```
<%= link_to admin_users_path(params: params.exclude(:subscription_payment_type_eq).permit) do %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we decided to implement it this way:

```
<%= link_to admin_users_path(
            params: { q: params.require(:q).permit(params[:q].keys - ["address_province_eq"]) }
          ) do %>
```

We basically substract the filter's key from the current params when passing it in the `link_to`

Answer (score 0):

Permit expects a list of args and since you're not sending any no params will be passed to your controller. I'm actually not sure how your calling permit without args is even working. Anyway maybe you can try it like this instead:

```
 <%= link_to admin_users_path(params: params[:q].except(:subscription_payment_type_eq.permit!)
```